# Illegal characters in path asp.net and utf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webclient, illegal-characters, downloadstring

i want get content of web page but when try to access it show this error
"Illegal characters in path"
my question is how i solve it and there is a better way to get content of a page
now i get content with windows application and webbrowser and have no error but cant do in asp
my code

```
      Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("www.url.com/")
```

and content of page is

```
20141105@5058.00@4850.00@4997.00@4870.00@4920.00@4880.00@13553984180.00@2712255@495;
```

if i change url to http://www.url.com/ the problem solve but character not support like

```
`‹�طG[T�ے-تAہ0ءI±°M/ùے«Zâœ–پ$¼×ى(م´;اy­iص)—½؛‚C%%û`
```

and i add this code but nor work

client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

Answer (score 0):

You should include [`http://`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) along with the URL to execute the query(`TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("www.url.com/")`) properly, so your code will be like the following:

```
 Dim client As New Net.WebClient
 TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("http://url.com/")
```

Comment: thank but not work site return error(500) no webpage is there